# Missing surfaces in exported model

Tags: export, import

please forgive my inexperience, i could really do with some help as spent days trying to sort this.
I am new to blender and modelling but my logic, experimentation and google searches which get me through issues seems to be failing me now.
I am having troubles with a Stadium mesh exporting into a game editor, some surfaces are not there and appears as if only half the model is showing up, as i can see the bounding box in the game editor is lower than exported model height.
[image: StadiumInBlender]
[image: GoalNetOnly]
[image: BoundingBoxShowingHalfStadiumHeight]
My mind is boggled as i have made the Net appear on one goal, but it refuses to appear on the other, also goal floors refuse to appear as well as top half of model.
I have more than quadruple checked settings in blender, also my config in game, nothing is wrong or different (well maybe wrong but not different lol) from one side of pitch to other, even using the same texture files for the hex patterns.
I have noticed it is also hit and miss whether or not the pitch (grass) shows up too, sometimes after export it does, other times not.
On top of this, if after exporting the .fbx i then import it back into blender, it has created/duplicated more textures assigned to my material groups, and also set transparency on items which were previously not set as transparent.
I have tried a lot of things including checking everything like UV positions, removing smooth/autosmooth, removing lights and camera, setting quads to tri's, resetting values, exporting with different options set, changing from mix to multiply and vica versa etc etc, which tbh most of what i did i don't even understand.
Like previously stated though i love to experiment as learn a lot this way, seeing the effects and changes helps me to understand the what and why behind it , just can't find what i'm doing wrong here, and to me it feels like logic doesn't apply..bangs head against wall. xD

Please Help me obi one kenobi, your my only hope :D
Thank you even if you only took the time to read this :)

P.S If you know how i can easily join the hex pattern on the roof corner edges, that would be very usefull and save me the time of editing an image till i get them lined up.

Edit coming for .blend file to be included :)
[image]

Further Info...
Here is a short sample of configuration within the game files.
I have removed the rest of it as the sample should give a basic overall impression of how this game handles things and some of the options.

```
       "col": "$MOD_DATA/Collision/noCol_col.obj",
        "defaultColors": {
            "Pitch": "FFFFFF",
            "StadiumBottom": "000000",
            "OrangeHexesPitch": "FF7400",
            "OrangePitchRamps": "FF7400",
            "OrangeGoalPosts": "FF7400",
            "OrangeGoalSmallHexGlass": "FF7400",
            "OrangeGoalRamps": "FF7400",
            "OrangeGoalFloor": "FF7400",
            "BlueHexesPitch": "0074FF",
            "BluePitchRamps": "0074FF",
            "BlueGoalPosts": "0074FF",
            "BlueGoalSmallHexGlass": "0074FF",
            "BlueGoalRamps": "0074FF",
            "BlueGoalFloor": "0074FF",
            "GoalLines": "0074FF"
        },
        "name": "DFH_Stadium",
        "physics": {
            "mass": 10000,
            "material": "Plastic"
        },
        "renderable": {
            "lodList": [
                {
                    "includes": [
                        "POSITION",
                        "NORMAL",
                        "UV0",
                        "TANGENT"
                    ],
                    "maxViewDistance": 4500,
                    "mesh": "$MOD_DATA/Mesh/TESTING_074.fbx",
                    "subMeshMap": {
                        "Pitch": {
                            "custom": {
                                "color": "Pitch"
                            },
                            "material": "DifAsgNor",
                            "textureList": [
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/DFH_Stadium_4096_dif.tga",
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/_asg.png",
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/_nor.png"
                            ]
                        },
                        "StadiumBottom": {
                            "custom": {
                                "color": "StadiumBottom"
                            },
                            "material": "DifAsgNor",
                            "textureList": [
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/StadiumBottom.tga",
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/_asg.png",
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/_nor.png"
                            ]
                        },
                        "OrangeHexesPitch": {
                            "custom": {
                                "color": "OrangeHexesPitch"
                            },
                            "material": "DifAsgNorAlpha",
                            "textureList": [
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/HexLarge_dif3.tga",
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/HexLarge_asg.tga",
                                "$MOD_DATA/Textures/HexLarge_nor.tga"
```

And so on..
As you can see the game itself specifies the material types and textures used, i have also more options of which i have tried many combinations, including "DifAsgNorAlphaFlip" DifAsgNorAlphaBackface" etc, i also tried different images saved in different ways, although now mainly use the one's i have set on the goal net that does appear as know they must work.
I previously had an issue with paint.net exporting the .tga whereas with gimp the exact same image loaded in, no adjustment, then saved worked and solved that issue.
The game editor also allows for color changes associated with material types, i had planned on creating a much more detailed stadium, with ability to change colors too, hence why i have so many listed, i did remove some and start to simplify things, no doubt will do that more as helps with fault finding and adjustments :)
However i still cannot get my head around why i have the orange goal hex pattern working, yet with exactly the same config settings, and blender settings for blue goal it still refuses to appear.
Note i also used mirror to create the Stadium so it should be pretty much the same as other goal in terms of geometry.
I have checked the face directions using the backface culling option, selecting all then ctrl N made half of what was displayed disappear in game.
Again thank you Mr Zak for your time in trying to help, any suggestions are great and at least give me some hope again ;)
In case wondering the game this is for is called Scrap Mechanic.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Maybe try applying scale (Object mode > Ctrl+A) then recalculating normals (Edit mode > select all > Ctrl+N), they could be flipped which then will make them disappear in the game (technically not drawn). Note also that mesh should have some thickness in order to be visible in the game from both sides.  As to materials they won't be exported that precisely via FBX so I don't think there's a way to preserve them. Bake textures and import them instead.

Comment: Thank you @Mr Zak for the reply.  I have tried what you suggested, unfortunately this has not solved the issue.  I had thought about the thickness maybe an issue, but dismissed it due to the fact one goal net i have managed to display from both sides (inside and out) and that is only 1 layer thick. Maybe the distance between top-bottom and side to side falls within some form of requirement?  The materials themselves are listed within the config, and also what kind of textures and link to textures used also within the config, i will update the description to include a sample of config in a mo.

Comment: I tried adding geometry to make the stadium upper half double thickness, this did not appear in game either.  I will try contact game devs to see if there is a limit on model size or any other restrictions i am not aware of, also will try splitting the mesh to just one side of pitch, test, then a quarter and so on whilst retaining part of the different types to see if can gather more info or point towards issues, although that may help it would not explain why the exported fbx imports back into blender with different settings. So many things confusing me right now haha.

Comment: Sorry for all comments, but best to keep informed i feel as don't want to waste anyone's time who's willing to help. Before splitting mesh i decided to test theory on mesh size, it appears the game has no problem displaying the complete mesh once all material groups were removed and just a basic one applied. Maybe a limitation there within game?  4am now but tomorrow will start to rebuild the groups simplified, then add more one by one testing till i get to the point something doesn't work and go from there. Should have done this before i guess, will let you know of the outcome asap.

Comment: On combining material groups to end up with only 5 in total (min needed, did the half trick to save time on adding one by one lol) the whole mesh loads into the game, with all the pitch being shown as intended, both sides seeing the hex pattern, and able to change colors if needed.  This may not be the answer as to why i had certain problems, but does point towards something to do with the material groups. As much as i would love to know where and when it breaks to help pinpoint the issue, i feel i lost enough time, so will leave until i next suffer the same type of occurrence :D